# Gmail force consistent date formatting

Tags: gmail, userscripts

By default, the date format in Gmail changes depending on how long ago that date was:

- Mails from the same day show only the time and how long ago that was eg 2:03 PM (2 hours ago)
- Mails from recent days include the day, date, time, and how long ago it was, eg
  Tue, Jan 11, 5:24 PM (9 days ago)
- Older mails include the day, date and time, eg
  Sat, Dec 25, 2021, 10:05 AM

How can I change this into a consistent format when reading mails? The methods mentioned here: [https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/89499/change-gmail-date-format-to-iso-8601-i-e-yyyy-mm-dd#:~:text=You%20do%20have%20to%20set,most%20other%20date%20format%20strings](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/89499/change-gmail-date-format-to-iso-8601-i-e-yyyy-mm-dd#:%7E:text=You%20do%20have%20to%20set,most%20other%20date%20format%20strings). only seem to change the date format when in the inbox view, not the date shown in the top corner when reading an email. Specifically I have run the userscript from Magnus using tampermonkey, and also the extension suggested by MBraedley, but I don't really have the knowledge to make any changes to these myself to accomplish what I need, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In the Chrome Web Store, there is a plug-in called [Gmail Date Time Formatter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail-date-time-formatter/nkmaeogddfijadboccpafnmhkjhidgeb/) that does the trick.

This plug-in also lets you select the ISO8601 format via YYYY-MM-DD.